# Relationship between eigenvalues of differential operator and eigenvalues of its adjoint operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, adjoint-operators

I am considering $L\phi = -\triangle \phi + u \cdot \nabla \phi$ and its "adjoint" operator $L^* \phi = -\triangle \phi - \nabla \cdot (\phi u)$ on a bounded domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Here $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz, and also I want to impose that all inputs to $L$ or $L^*$ are zero on $\partial \Omega$.

I would like to say that $L$ has the exact same eigenvalues as $L^*$, or at the very minimum, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $L$ then it is also an eigenvalue for $L^*$.
Firstly I'm not sure if the "adjoint" operator $L^*$ is actually the adjoint of $L$ in the functional analysis sense.
If it is, I am not totally sure what spaces I should be looking at. My first guess would be $L:W^{2,2}(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ but I don't really know.

Explanation and good reference books (specifically with treatment of adjoints of differential operators) are both appreciated.

Comment: If $L$ is defined with a domain consisting of functions which do not satisfy boundary conditions, then $L^{\star}$ normally has a domain consisting of functions with all $0$ boundary data. While $L$ may have non-zero eigenfunctions, $L^{\star}$ is not likely to have any if its domain consists of functions with all $0$ boundary data. Start by considering the simplest operator $L=i\frac{d}{dx}$ with no boundary conditions on a finite interval. Ref: Reed & Simon Volume II on Fourier Analysis, Selfadjointness .

Comment: I forgot to mention, $\phi=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Both operators I want to come with zero boundary conditions.

Comment: The adjoint equation leads to integration-by-parts-type evaluation terms. It's making those evaluation terms vanish that tells the story of what domain is required for the adjoint.